# Run vlc extension from command line

Tags: lua, vlc

I have a vlc extension written in Lua. I know how to run it from the GUI (View -> My Extension). I want to run it from the command line, so I would not need to start X every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not yet implemented. See ticket [#3883](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/3883)

Comment: Ticket creation was at 2010, 10 years ago and we still waiting for a solution...